# Update another column during a update query based on its new value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table named item_quantity with 2 fields, quantity and requested. I have a query which will update the field quantity every time a customer buy. The problem is i want to update the column requested to 0 when the quantity becomes 0. This is what i tried so far.

```
UPDATE `item_quantity`SET `quantity`=quantity-5,`requested`= CASE when `quantity` = 0 then 0 else 1 end where `item_id`=1;
```

But the case is underlined red. I don't know if its syntax or logical error. How will i do this? Thank you in advance! 
[[This is what i got][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUMUW.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUMUW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the update requested after you have set item_quantity. Then you can directly compare item_quantity like this:

```
UPDATE `item_quantity`
SET
  `quantity`= `quantity` - 5
  ,`requested`= IF(`quantity` = 0, 0, `requested`);
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM item_quantity;
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | quantity | requested |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 |       10 |         9 |
+----+----------+-----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE `item_quantity`
    -> SET
    ->   `quantity`= `quantity` - 5
    ->   ,`requested`= IF(`quantity` = 0, 0, `requested`);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM item_quantity;
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | quantity | requested |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 |        5 |         9 |
+----+----------+-----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE `item_quantity`
    -> SET
    ->   `quantity`= `quantity` - 5
    ->   ,`requested`= IF(`quantity` = 0, 0, `requested`);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM item_quantity;
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | quantity | requested |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 |        0 |         0 |
+----+----------+-----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: I tried that but starting from IF to semicolon its always red underlined. I guess my syntax was wrong. How can i fixed it? It only say unexpected token

Comment: @healer - can you please post your query

Comment: @healer - there must a typo in your query. i have add a sample in my answer

Comment: I understand your query but when i try i still got same error

Comment: can you also show us the table schema, to what type requested has

Comment: try it without the backticks. there is noch field like a keyword

Comment: Sir its working. I guess i just need to clear cookies. To see the result of changes ive made

Comment: Sir i don't get it why its underlined red but when i run the query it take effect

Comment: I like PHPMyAdmin, great tool. i never used it in the last 10 years. Do you have a better tool like sequel pro for MAc or Workbench

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger.
This trigger will fire just before the update will execute, and you can update the other field.
Try the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER item_quantity_before_update
BEFORE UPDATE
   ON item_quantity FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DECLARE old_quantity NUMBER;
   DECLARE new_quantity NUMBER;

   SELECT quantity INTO old_quantity;

   SET new_quantity = old_quantity - 5;
   IF new_quantity == 0 THEN
      SET new.requested = 0
   ELSE
      SET new.requested = 1;
   END IF;
END; //
```